# Kendo UI Mobile List View example not working with my code

Tags: javascript, json, mobile, kendo-ui

**Background:** With some help (@korchev) I was able to figure out how to use JSONP to bind data to a template. (see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danieldropik/ekVYM/1/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22216422/2115934)). However, I wanted to be able to make the data displayed in a kendo UI Mobile List view as mentioned in [the Kendo Docs](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/databinding.html).

Unfortunately, the mobile-list view [example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/databinding.html), uses arrays of data coded in the html which is unlike jsonp.

Also, I notice that the official [mobile list-view example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/databinding.html) leaves this out : `<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">`. And that is a problem because my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/danieldropik/ekVYM/1/) relies on that implementation.

**Summary:** I am new to the kendo UI mobile framework, and I don't understand how to use my existing code to yield a mobile list view. Sometimes I find the documentation confusing, and I would please like somebody to assist.

**My code:**

```
<div id="products"></div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="product">
        <p>#:title#</p>
        <p>#:content#</p>
        <p>#= author.slug #</p>
    </div>
</script>

   <script>

$(function() {
        var template = kendo.template($("#template").html());

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            schema: {
                data: function(response) {
                    return [response.post];
                }
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://www.techhelix.com/?json=get_post&id=1/",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
            },
            requestStart: function() {

                kendo.ui.progress($("#products"), true);
            },
            requestEnd: function() {

               kendo.ui.progress($("#products"), false);
               console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSource, null, 4));

            },
            change: function() {

               $("#products").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
            }

        });

        dataSource.read();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Kendo can be confusing to learn. Please post some code so I can see where you're at.

Comment: @RickS added the code I am working with. It is the same as the code that is on the jsfiddle I provided. (http://jsfiddle.net/danieldropik/ekVYM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, I would first start out with the Kendo Mobile List View example and get that working.
Once that works, you can do the following to bind to your datasource and template.

```
function mobileListViewDataBindInitGrouped() {

    ...Code for getting your dataSource here...

    $("#products").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
        fixedHeaders: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this asap. Also, please see the comment I just left on @Korchev's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to bind the list view to your data source. Here is a quick example:

```
<div data-role="view">
  <ul data-role="listview" 
      data-source="myDataSource" 
      data-template="template"></ul>
  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
  <div class="product">
    <p>#:title#</p>
    <p>#=content#</p>
    <p>#= author.slug #</p>
  </div>
 </script>
 </div>
 <script>
 var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    data: function(response) {
      return [response.post];
    }
  },
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://www.techhelix.com/?json=get_post&id=1/",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  }
});
 var application = new kendo.mobile.Application();
</script>
```

Also available live: http://jsbin.com/nisuzapu/1/edit

Comment: Thank you. My expected outcome was to have the listview contain the list of all the titles. When selected, a detailed view will display the contents.Similar to (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/fixedheaders.html) ..I created this(http://jsbin.com/cisik/1/). I have a feeling there is a more efficient way for me to set up response.post so it is like an array, rather than trying to repeat what you did above for each title.

Comment: Your data source returns only one title. You need to return more than one to display them as listview items.